# SAP HANA dark theme change sql script text colors/syntax highlighting

Tags: hana, hana-studio

I changed SAP HANA studio to the dark theme, but the text in the editor is difficult to see. I've searched through all the preferences for about 30 minutes but I still can't find any way to change this.

There are some posts in the SAP Community asking this same question (with no solution yet):

https://answers.sap.com/questions/12980770/dark-theme-with-hana-studio-not-supporting-sql-scr.html

https://answers.sap.com/questions/12895423/how-do-i-change-the-font-color-in-hana-studio-sql.html

SAP HANA Studio

Version: 2.3.41

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The build-in options to change the color themes are pretty limited.

Given that SAP does not further develop SAP HANA Studio - it is deprecated and superseded by the WebIDE - the only option I found is to use a 3rd party tool to change the theme:

[Darkest Dark Theme with DevStyle](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle) from [Genuitec](https://www.genuitec.com/products/devstyle/).

I just added the "software site" URL (`http://www.genuitec.com/updates/devstyle/ci/`) to the HANA Studio Eclipse and installed the **DevStyle**  product.

This resulted in a look like this:

[image: Dark HANA Studio theme]

It does not provide detailed control over the syntax-highlighting, though. So if you're after choosing which SQL keywords get which colour then you're out of luck with SAP HANA Studio.

Comment: Perfect man. Thank u. To other guys, just go to HELP > INSTALL NEW SOFTWARE and paste the link.